# NoReverseMatch dispite following examples

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am fairly new to Django - Having followed many examples and tutorials online - I have produced my various models over some time. I have run into an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /Organisation/organisations Reverse for 'Organisation' not found. 'Organisation' is 
not a valid view function or pattern name.' 
Request Method: GET Request
URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Organisation/organisations Django 
Version:    3.0 
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch 
Exception Value:     Reverse for 'Organisation' not found. 'Organisation' is not a valid view 
function or pattern name.
```

The details for the code I'm using is as follows:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        #Returns the url to access a detail record for organisation.
        return reverse('Organisation.views.OrganisationDetail', args=[str(self.Form_Field_OrgID)])
```

My Relevant Model -

```
Form_Field_OrgID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Form_Field_OrgName = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Organisation Name', verbose_name = "Organisation Name")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgCountry = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Select Organisation Country', verbose_name = "Organisation Country")
    Form_Field_OrgPcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text='Enter Organisation Post Code', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter Organisation Email', verbose_name = "Organisation Email Address")
    Form_Field_OrgPhone = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text='Enter Organisation Phone Number', verbose_name = "Organisation Phone Number")
    Form_Field_OrgWebAddr = models.URLField(max_length=250, help_text='Enter Organisation Web Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Web Address")
    Form_Field_OrgVisible = models.BooleanField ( help_text='Is This Organisation Visable', verbose_name = "Show Organisation")
    Form_Field_OrgAddedBy = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Who is Enter the Information', verbose_name = "Added By")
    Form_Field_OrgDateAdded = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name = "Date Added")
    Form_Field_OrgUserDefined = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter any other Details', verbose_name = "Organisation Notes")
```

My Relevant view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from Organisation.models import Organisation, Departments, OrgDrtRpt
from django.views import generic

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')




  class OrganisationList(ListView):
    model = Organisation
    context_object_name ='all_organisations'



    class OrganisationDetail(DetailView):
    model = Organisation 
    context_object_name ='organisation_detail' 

My Urls.py

    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    app_name ='Organisation'


    urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', OrganisationList.as_view()),
    path('details/<uuid:pk>', OrganisationDetail.as_view(), name ='organisation_detail'),


]
```

my organisation_list.html

```
{% extends 'baseNotLoggedIn.html' %}

{% block title %}Organisation Home {% endblock title %}
{% block nav-style %}mkt-nav{% endblock nav-style %}

{% block content %} 

    {% if organisation_list %}
    <h1>All Organisations total ={{num_Organisations}}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for Organisation in organisation_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{Organisation.get_absolute_url}}">{{Organisation.Form_Field_OrgName}}</a>({{Organisation.Form_Field_OrgAddr}}) <p>There are some</p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p> There are no organisations available </p>

    {%endif%}
    {# Hero Section #}  

    {# Main Section #}

{% endblock content %}
```

If i change the get_absolute_url to a return render, the list view works ok....but i still get the no reverse match error

Comment: The folder structure is: The folder Structure is as Follow: 

     

Project--|-templates
         |-Project
         |-Organisation--| 
                         |-templates --|
                         |              |-Organisation-|
                                                      |-Organisation_detail.html
                                                       |-Organisation_list.html
                           


admin.py
                           urls.py
                           views.py.

Comment: forgot to add - if I use return "/organisation_detail/%s'" %(self.Form_Field_OrgID) then the organisation-list.html works ok. as soon as i click on the link for the details i get : 
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/organisation_detail/66e18079-0f78-465b-ba54-e5963bd65aa2'

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces):

```
reverse('Organisation:Organisation', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Side note, it's Django industry standard to snake case url names:

```
reverse('organisation:organisation', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Ive changed the get_absolute_url to: return reverse('Organisation:Organisation', kwargs={'pk':self.pk}) and now get: NoReverseMatch at /Organisation/organisations
Reverse for 'Organisation' with keyword arguments '{'pk': UUID('8565ce04-abe6-45db-ab47-9d1032088af4')}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Organisation/organisation/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Comment: That error message is telling you that you need to change your url to allow for a `uuid` format. Right now your url is expect all numbers.

Comment: Forgot to say I changed to uuid:<pk>

Comment: Ive chnaged to this - reverse('Organisation:Organisation', kwargs={'uuid':self.pk})

Answer (score 0):

So... after a few days:

I have now managed to test my urls.py and views.py -

The Views.py :

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView,CreateView
from Organisation.models import Organisation

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')


class OrganisationList(ListView):
    template_name = 'organisation_list'
    model = Organisation
    context_object_name ='organisation_list'


class OrganisationDetail(DetailView):
    model = Organisation 
    context_object_name ='organisation_detail'
```

with urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from Organisation.views import OrganisationList,OrganisationDetail,OrganisationCreate
from django.conf.urls.static import static
app_name ='Organisation'
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('list/', OrganisationList.as_view()),
    path('create/', OrganisationCreate.as_view()),
    path('details/<uuid:pk>', OrganisationDetail.as_view(), name ='organisation_detail'),
```

the organisation_list.html looks like this:

```
{% extends 'baseNotLoggedIn.html' %}

{% block title %}Organisation Home {% endblock title %}
{% block nav-style %}mkt-nav{% endblock nav-style %}

{% block content %} 

    {% if organisation_list %}



        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name </th>
                    <th scope="col">Address</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for Organisation in organisation_list %}
            <tr>


                <td><a href="{{Organisation.get_absolute_url}}">{{Organisation.Form_Field_OrgName}}</a></td>
                <td>{{Organisation.Form_Field_OrgAddr}}</td>
                <td>{{Organisation.Form_Field_OrgPhone}}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>


    {% else %}
        <p> There are no ations available </p>

    {%endif%}
    {# Hero Section #}  

    {# Main Section #}

{% endblock content %}
```

THe models.py Looks like:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.urls import reverse

# Class defines the organisation - Organisation part of superclass - Actors  / All Fields are mandatory
class Organisation(models.Model):

    Form_Field_OrgID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Form_Field_OrgName = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter Organisation Name', verbose_name = "Organisation Name")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgAddr4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter Organisation Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgCountry = models.CharField(max_length=2, help_text='Select Organisation Country', verbose_name = "Organisation Country")
    Form_Field_OrgPcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text='Enter Organisation Post Code', verbose_name = "Organisation Address")
    Form_Field_OrgEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Enter Organisation Email', verbose_name = "Organisation Email Address")
    Form_Field_OrgPhone = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text='Enter Organisation Phone Number', verbose_name = "Organisation Phone Number")
    Form_Field_OrgWebAddr = models.URLField(max_length=250, help_text='Enter Organisation Web Address', verbose_name = "Organisation Web Address")
    Form_Field_OrgVisible = models.BooleanField ( help_text='Is This Organisation Visable', verbose_name = "Show Organisation")
    Form_Field_OrgAddedBy = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Who is Enter the Information', verbose_name = "Added By")
    Form_Field_OrgDateAdded = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name = "Date Added")
    Form_Field_OrgUserDefined = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter any other Details', verbose_name = "Organisation Notes")
    # string to represent the model object
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Form_Field_OrgName

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #Returns the url to access a detail record for organisation.
        #return reverse('Organisation:organisation_details', 'pk:self.pk')
      # return '/Organisations/details/%i' % str(self.Form_Field_OrgID)
        #return reverse('Organisation:OrganisationDetail', kwargs={'uuid':self.pk})
        return reverse('organisation_detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

I have tried a combination now of various get_absolute_url(self): as can be seem above from the commented out section. All of these either do not work with:

NoReverseMatch at /Organisation/list/
Reverse for 'organisation' not found. 'organisation' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Organisation/list/

similarly on the /admin/ site i click on the organisation view on site using

```
return reverse('Organisation:OrganisationDetail'...... i get the following
```

NoReverseMatch at /admin/r/11/0b611e28-bcad-426f-a713-4259f4ec093c/
Reverse for 'model-detail-view' not found. 'model-detail-view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/r/11/0b611e28-bcad-426f-a713-4259f4ec093c/

I have looked at the various examples in the docs but nothing is making sense -